# Reusing a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I made a randomizer to choose what movie i want to see.
First, the program asksyou for the number of movies, and the requires the names of those movies. Depending on the number that you entered before are going to be the attempts that you have to introduce the movies.
For that the button that pushes the information of the entry into the program has to be "recycled".
The `print(x)` in the second function is to check if the variable has been passed from the first one.
After passing the x my program doesn't do anything else.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

#generación de ventana
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Decidir que ver con Mora")
window.geometry("600x500")
window.configure(background="light blue")

x = None
item = ""
list = []
len_list = len(list)

def cantidad_items():
    x= int(texto1.get())
    boton1.configure(text = "Ingresar", command= lambda:añadir(x))
    
def añadir(x):
    print(x)
    if len_list < x:
        item = texto1.get()
        list.append(item)
    else:
        print(random.choice(list))

#primer entry del número
texto1 = ttk.Entry(window, font = "Helvetica 20", width = 22)
texto1.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)
#texto1.insert(0, "Ingrese la cantidad de ítems")

#botón ejecución del input
boton1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Ingresar", command = cantidad_items)
boton1.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, anchor=CENTER)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `len_list` is always zero - the length of the list at the moment you assigned that variable.  It isn't going to magically update when the list changes length.

Comment: but if i´m adding an item every time i click the button why the lenght of the list doesn´t grow? how do i solve this problem?

Comment: The *list* grows.  The variable, that you set once at the start of the program, doesn't change.  You don't need the variable at all, it's simple enough to call `len()` again whenever you need to know the current length.  (And find a better name than `list` for the list, you've overwritten a rather basic built-in Python name.)

Comment: thanks, i made the variable just in case i wouldn't be able to check the lenght, i cannot believe it was such a simple mistake

Answer (score 0):

The function that your button is attached to has to be called by using parenthases afterward. eg. cantidad_items() in order to call a function, you need to use parenthases after the function name. Also, your function doesn't have much happening inside it, which contains all the things that will happen once you press the button.

This website might help. Sorry it isn't in spanish!
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: that's wrong, you don't use parenthases to command the function into a button, the problem was that i used a var to refer to a lenght but i didn't need the extra step. You can see the solution was commented in my post directly